# How to load cordova webview in my viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova, webview

My cordova library was old and had to update it because of iOS11. I have updated it to latest version 4.4.0. CDVViewController is totally different now which enables webviewEngine that takes UIWebview or WKWebview. How do I initiate Cordova webview in my native app. Previously, I loaded it like this -

```
 - (void) viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        CDVViewController *viewController = [CDVViewController new];
        viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
        viewController.startPage = @"blank.html";
        viewController.view.frame = self.webView.frame;
        [self.webView removeFromSuperview];
        self.webView = nil;
        [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
        self.webView = viewController.webView;
        viewController.webView.delegate = self;
        self.cordovaWebViewController = viewController;
        self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

        if (self.url)
          [self.webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: self.url]];
     }
```

And used webview delegates as

```
#pragma mark Webview Delegate
- (void) webViewDidStartLoad: (UIWebView *) webViewLocal {
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
        [self.cordovaWebViewController webViewDidStartLoad:webViewLocal];
    }

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webViewLocal {
     [self.spinner stopAnimating];
     [self.cordovaWebViewController webViewDidFinishLoad:webViewLocal];
    }

- (void) webView: (UIWebView *) webView didFailLoadWithError: (NSError *) error {
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
  }

      - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        if ([request.URL.absoluteString hasSuffix: @"link_restart_movie_file"]) {
            [self loadItem];
            return NO;
        }
        [self.webView loadRequest: request];
        return NO;
    }
     [self.cordovaWebViewController webView:self.webView      shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
     return YES;
    }
```

How do I use WebviewEngine to load in my viewcontroller? Is there any tutorial, that explains the usage of CDVViewController? Please help! Thanks!